# Nodejs RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, caused by sending object in response

Tags: node.js, express

It would be awesome if anyone can give me a helping hand with this problem.

I am currently running into a problem where calling this express route is giving me the error show below a RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

It only seems to happen when I include the res.json(users[user]); function. If I substitute this function with res.send('Done'); the function runs fine.

I have tried setTimeout, setImmediate and process.nextTick, all giving me the same error, just about.

I'm sorta hoping it's a silly mistake on my end.

```
//Send Friend Request
router.post('/send/friend/request', auth, function(req, res, next){

 var query = User.find({$or: [
  {username: req.body.username},
  {username: req.payload.username}
 ]})
 .select(' username friends notifications');

 query.exec(function(err, users){
  if(err) return next(err);
  if(users.length < 2) console.log('/send/friend/request - There was an error      in accessing the users from the db');
  else{

   //Identify users in array
   var user = users.findIndex(function(element, index){
    if(element.username === req.payload.username)
      return element;
    });
   var requestUser = (user + 1) % 2;

   //addFriends
   users[user].friends.push({
     user: users[requestUser],
   });

   users[requestUser].friends.push({
     user: users[user],
     sent: false
   });

   //notifications
   users[user].notifications.push({ 
     user: users[requestUser],  
     type: 0, 
     summary: "Your friend request has been sent to " + req.body.username +".",
     status: "Pending..."
   });

   users[requestUser].notifications.push({
     user: users[user],  
     type: 1, 
     summary: "You have a new friend request from " + req.payload.username + ".",
     status: "Pending..."
   });

   users[requestUser].save(function(err){
     if(err) return next(err);
   });

   users[user].save(function(err){
    if(err) return next(err);
   });

     //Here lies the culprit
     res.json(users[user]);
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Perhaps**

If `user` contains reference by itself then `res.json` fail. Because `req.json` attempt to explode `unlimited` object. To avoid this problem you can:

1. Specify user fields to send

   `res.send(JSON.stringify(user, ['name', 'age', ...]))`
2. Define reference as not enumerable property

   `Object.defineProperty(user, 'your-ref', {enumerable: false});`

Comment: Yes! res.json was attempting to explode the unlimited object as you said. I specified all the other fields except the user ref and it fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a circular reference between `users[user]` and `users[requestUser]`.

Here's an example that demonstrates the problem:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = Schema({ friends : [] });
const User       = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

let user1 = new User();
let user2 = new User();

user1.friends.push(user2); 
user2.friends.push(user1); // the circular reference is created here

console.log( JSON.stringify(user1) );
```

`JSON.stringify()` will thrown a `RangeError` because of that circular reference.

You may need to rethink your schema, as I don't think you can use [subdocs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) for your purpose. Instead, you should use ["population"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to store references between documents.

When you change the schema above to the following, it won't throw:

```
const userSchema = Schema({
  friends : [ { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'User' } ]
});
```

**EDIT**: if you're using a complex object as array contents, even with population, you should push `_id` values and not documents:

```
users[user].friends.push({
  user: users[requestUser]._id,
});
```

Comment: This is what I currently have as friends in my User Schema

    friends: [{ 
        user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        friendRequest: { type: Boolean , default: true},
        sent: { type: Boolean , default:  true},
        accepted: { type: Boolean , default: false}
    }],

I am not sure this is the problem.

Comment: @MatrixEntry1337 in that case, you may have to use `.push({ user: users[requestUser]._id })`

Answer (score 0):

Definitely object `users` is not JSON.Its POJO object with additional mongo properties  which contain recursive referance to `__proto__` property.

Do either serialization and then de-serialize on client side again.

OR extract the  property in new Object literal then pass to it `resp.json()`